# SharePoint bulk update of multiple list items

Tags: rest, datatables, sharepoint-2013

I am currently working with binding SharePoint list items using JQuery datatables and rest API with the following code from Microsoft samples. I want to extend the sample to include multiple selection of row items with check boxes so that I can then another method to update the selected items. Please let me if this is possible with any guidance

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<table id="requests" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Business unit</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Due date</th>
            <th>Assigned to</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<script>
// UMD
(function(factory) {
    "use strict";

    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // AMD
        define(['jquery'], function ($) {
            return factory( $, window, document );
        });
    }
    else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
        // CommonJS
        module.exports = function (root, $) {
            if (!root) {
                root = window;
            }

            if (!$) {
                $ = typeof window !== 'undefined' ?
                    require('jquery') :
                    require('jquery')( root );
            }

            return factory($, root, root.document);
        };
    }
    else {
        // Browser
        factory(jQuery, window, document);
    }
}
(function($, window, document) {
    $.fn.dataTable.render.moment = function (from, to, locale) {
        // Argument shifting
        if (arguments.length === 1) {
            locale = 'en';
            to = from;
            from = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
        }
        else if (arguments.length === 2) {
            locale = 'en';
        }

        return function (d, type, row) {
            var m = window.moment(d, from, locale, true);

            // Order and type get a number value from Moment, everything else
            // sees the rendered value
            return m.format(type === 'sort' || type === 'type' ? 'x' : to);
        };
    };
}));
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#requests').DataTable({
        'ajax': {
        'url': "../_api/web/lists/getbytitle('IT Requests')/items?$select=ID,BusinessUnit,Category,Status,DueDate,AssignedTo/Title&$expand=AssignedTo/Title",
        'headers': { 'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata' },
        'dataSrc': function(data) {
            return data.value.map(function(item) {
                return [
                    item.ID,
                    item.BusinessUnit,
                    item.Category,
                    item.Status,
                    new Date(item.DueDate),
                    item.AssignedTo.Title
                ];
            });
        }
    },
    columnDefs: [{
        targets: 4,
        render: $.fn.dataTable.render.moment('YYYY/MM/DD')
    }]
    });
});
</script>
```